# В чем разница между SmsManager и этим кодом: Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

Tags: android, android-sdk

Я никак не могу понять, это две разные реализации одного и того же или что-то из этого устарело?

Я нашел реализацию через Cursor в посту 14 летней давности: [How can I read SMS messages from the device programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Пока нет ответа более корректного, отвечу как я понял спустя какое-то время.

Разница в том, что SmsManager отправляет и получает Sms, а код который я нашел:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
```

Получает доступ к базе данных смс и далее с помощью методов Cursor можно как курсором пройтись по базе в поисках нужного смс сообщения или же просто сделать dump всех сообщений - крч, парсить как хочется можно.